# Error: Subquery returns more than 1 row, when using IN

Tags: mysql

I have a problem why the query is an error when I use IN inside the IF

```
SET @level  := '2';
SET @id_user    := '2';

SELECT *
FROM pg_akun
WHERE 
    level_akun = @level
    AND parent_id_akun IN (
        IF(@level IN ('1', '2'), (SELECT DISTINCT(parent_id_akun) FROM pg_akun WHERE level_akun = @level), @id_user)
    )
    AND id_akun NOT IN (SELECT id_akun FROM pg_trans WHERE id_user = '1' AND pengajuan = '1')
```

Report error

```
Query: select * from pg_akun where level_akun = @level AND parent_id_akun in ( if(@level in ('1', '2'), (SELECT DISTINCT(parent_id_akun...

Error Code: 1242.
Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Comment: There must be more than one `parent_id_akun` that has `level_akun = @level`. That subquery has to return exactly 1 row.

Comment: Does `SELECT DISTINCT(parent_id_akun) FROM pg_akun WHERE level_akun = @level` return more than one row? Also it looks to me like you are using an IF inside an IN, not the other way around.

Comment: @JNevill He's doing both -- `@level IN ('1', '2')` is inside the `IF`.

Comment: Ah! yes. I suppose he is. I overlooked that one since it seemed like the `IF` inside the other `IN` is forcing the subquery to return a single row result, throwing the error. Like.. it's not the "IN inside the IF", it's the "IF inside the IN"... so to speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IF` has to return a single value, it can't return a derived table that can be used in `IN`.

Move the `IF` outside `IN`.

```
SELECT *
FROM pg_akun
WHERE 
    level_akun = @level
    AND IF(@level IN ('1', '2'),
            parent_id_akun IN (SELECT DISTINCT parent_id_akun FROM pg_akun WHERE level_akun = @level),
            parent_id_akun = @id_user)
    AND id_akun NOT IN (SELECT id_akun FROM pg_trans WHERE id_user = '1' AND pengajuan = '1')
```

BTW, `DISTINCT` is not a function that applies to a single column, it's a keyword that applies to the entire `SELECT` list. You don't need parentheses around the column name.

Comment: yes it works. thanks. it seems like I have been thinking too hard so that it is unthinkable and circling in logic. Thank you very much